# Why do ArrayLists not initialize in Web Services?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, arraylist

The client has a very old .net 1.1 app they need to hit a service. I built a middle piece in 4.0 that hits the service and I am attempting to return the data. The classes I built use ArrayLists since the .net 1.1 won't have access to generic lists. When the client consumes my code, the ArtayLists come over as ArrayOfAnyType and each must be initialized on the CLIENT side, despite the fact that I initialized them in Sub New(). I don't wan tthe client to have to initialize every arraylist. Here is the unremarkable code...

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class XApplication

    Public Sub New()
        _People = New ArrayList
        _PhysicalHouseholds = New ArrayList
        _TaxReturns = New ArrayList
    End Sub

    Public Property People() As ArrayList
    Public Property PhysicalHouseholds() As ArrayList
    Public Property TaxReturns() As ArrayList
End Class
```

Tried using the XmlInclude Attribute to define the class type but it had no effect. To be clear, I CAN NOT use WCF. I have to use web services.

Answer (score 0):

When a client proxy is generated from a web reference, the proxy will only model the data. Implementation code (including the constructor) cannot be obtained from `WSDL`. As a result, when a new instance of the proxy class is created, properties will have the default value.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Stuart. However, I am confused. Though I have never passed an ArrayList before, I have passes Classes with Objects and it seems they would have runinto the same issue but didn't.

Comment: Apols - I might not be understanding this correctly. Can I confirm you are publishing a service (.Net 4, but using a @WebService), and then consuming it as a 1.1 Web reference, leaving it to the wizard to generate proxy classes. Providing you don't share type, it usually doesn't matter what technology you use on the server - the client will create its own proxy off the WSDL). You might try expose a `List<Entity>` on the server - the 1.1 client should create custom classes (albeit with crazy names) to deserialize the data into.

Comment: What you describe is correct. I just went back and checked some old code where I send a class through web services. That class has properties that are classes. In sub new I initialize those classes. When I get it on the other end (consuming code) I only need to instaniate the top level class. I don't need to initialize all of the properties that are classes. The difference is these are classes and not arraylists, but still, I shouldn't need to instantiate them in the consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to create the object on the client side.

You can't send an object though a web service. The message that is sent is plain text, so any object has to be sent as the text representation that it contains, and be recreated on the client side by parsing the text and putting the data into a new object.